# SQL Agent job - no results, yet stored proc works

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, sql-agent-job

I have a SQL Agent Job which claims to succeed, however doesn't ACTUALLY do what it is supposed to do.  If I run the script inside on its own it does generate results.

I am using SQL 2014.  The scrip used/inside the agent job is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..##RCCON','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##RCCON

SELECT top 10 R.RC_C__ID as ConsentId
,dbo.clr_RC_CON(R.RC_CON__ID,'','') AS RC_CON
INTO ##RCCON FROM  RC_CON R
```

The script works independently, but as a JOB yields no results.

Any suggestions please?  Cheers

Comment: "as a JOB yields no results." Where are you checking the results? Are you looking at the job log or are you connecting through SSMS and selecting from that table?

Comment: put this into the same job step that consume the ##RCCON.

Answer (score 2):

The ##RCCON evaporates when the SQL Agent Job is done.  They only exist for the duration of the session.

Perhaps use [dbo].[RCCON] instead

Comment: Thankyou John - its a customer database so I was trying NOT to introduce tables into it for my benefit, but it looks like the only way to go.  Cheers.

Comment: What's one more table among friends?  I'm sure your client won't mind as long as there is a value-add.